# Trunking 802.1Q inside KVM via MacVTap

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I currently have the below setup, where `vm` is a KVM guest of `host` connected to one of `host`'s network interfaces via MacVTap operating in bridge mode.

```
               |---------------|
               |  ___________  |
switch ======= |  |   vm    |  |
               |  -----------  |
               |____ host _____|
```

Inside `vm`, I've set up a few VLAN interfaces alongside an untagged one:

```
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:00:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
4: enp2s0.2@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:00:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 65535 
    vlan protocol 802.1Q id 2 <REORDER_HDR> addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
...
```

`host` does not have any VLAN interfaces.

Untagged traffic flows in and out of `enp2s0` perfectly fine, but tagged traffic seems to get dropped somewhere between `host` and `vm`. I tested this by plugging in a machine into the interface represented by `enp2s0`, creating new tagged interfaces via `iproute2`, assigning an IP address, and then pinging the IP address of `vm` corresponding to the tagged VLAN from which I'm pinging.

Interestingly enough, running `tcpdump` on the raw backing interface on `host` lets the tagged packets through, but only while `tcpdump` is running. The below image shows this strange effect. (From top to bottom: `host`, running `tcpdump`; the machine plugged into `enp2s0`, pinging `vm`; `vm`, pinging said machine)

[image: terminals showing the impact of running tcpdump on VLAN packets]

Is it proper practice to be sending trunked traffic into a MacVTap interface, or should I be creating different interfaces on the host and passing those into the VM? Is there some sort of issue with how I'm setting up my interfaces, whether on the host or in the VM?

Comment: tcpdump by default puts the interface in promiscuous mode. if you run tcpdump with `-p` (to prevent promiscuous mode) I expect that tcpdump won't make it work anymore. As for the cause no idea.

Comment: Like you mentioned, the packets don't flow if I run `tcpdump` with the `-p` flag - good to know.

Comment: Did you change the MAC address of the interface (enp2s0) from the one which was inherited?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the raw backing interface on `host` to promiscuous mode seemed to make things work all the time (i.e. `ip link set dev enp2s0 promisc on` & adding the corresponding lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`). I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do, but for a lack of other things to try, this works fine for me until a better solution comes along.